# Stuck in a loop while password protecting a folder

Tags: applescript, password-protection

I wanted to make a folder action that requires a password to access the contents upon opening, and the current code is as follows:

```
on opening folder
    set login to true
    if login = true then
        tell application "Finder"
            close windows
        end tell
        set passw to display dialog ¬
            "Enter your password:" default answer ¬
            "" buttons {"Cancel", "Let me in!"} ¬
            default button 2 ¬
            giving up after 5 with hidden answer
        set entered to text returned of passw
        if entered = "password" then
            tell application "Finder"
                open folder "Myfolder"
            end tell
        end if
    end if
end opening folder
```

However, when `Myfolder` is opened, it obviously requires a password, and even when I enter it correctly, the window opens for a second and then closes, to require another entry of the password, and this continues on and on.

I presume this is because every time `Myfolder` is opened the script runs and requires a password, but how do I get around this? I have tried setting `login` to `false` after the `open folder "Myfolder"` and `end tell` but this does not word as `login` is set to `true` every time the script is run.

How can I stop the script requiring a password forever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
property passwordWasGiven : false

on opening folder theFolder
    if passwordWasGiven is false then
        tell application "Finder"
            close theFolder
        end tell
        set passw to display dialog ¬
            "Enter your password:" default answer ¬
            "" buttons {"Cancel", "Let me in!"} ¬
            default button 2 ¬
            giving up after 5 with hidden answer
        set entered to text returned of passw
        if entered = "password" then
            set passwordWasGiven to true
            tell application "Finder"
                open folder theFolder
            end tell
        end if
    else
        set passwordWasGiven to false
    end if
end opening folder
```

Properties are preserved across script runs, so `passwordWasGiven` becomes a toggle for whether a correct password was entered.

But please, this is a poor, poor way to password-protect a folder. People can see the contents of the folder for a moment before the Finder closes it; people can access the contents easily on the command line; people can read the script to discover the password. Anyone with half-a-brain can get in. If you want to make a secure folder, use Disk Utility or diskutil on the command line and make an encrypted disk image. That is no more difficult than using a folder — you double-click on it to open it, just like you would with a folder — but the password is secure (assuming you choose to save it in keychain) and the encryption is strong.